# WPF/Silverlight Prism 4 and Express editions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, prism

I am interested in Prism v4, and noticed under requirements that it needs Visual Studio Professional or higher.  Can Prism work with the VS2010 Express editions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can, see the note under step 1:

> Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition can
>   be used to develop Prism applications
>   using the Prism Library.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405471(PandP.40).aspx

Comment: Excellent, that is good to hear.  Now if only a subversion project could be used easier with the Express editions... I'm resorting to TortoiseSVN to manage the source control aspects.